# Handling in a WPF application SEHException thrown from a mixed C++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf, dll

I have a mixed C++ dll (my.dll) that is used in a WPF application.
The C++ code of the dll can throw some 'legal' guard exceptions (like preconditions and postconditions), that should not crash the application.
 When my.dll is used in a C++ application the exceptions are catched and the application continues to run.
When my.dll is used in a WPF application the exceptions are converted in `System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException`, catched using this code:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(GlobalExceptionHandler);
static void GlobalExceptionHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
  Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
  // ...
}
```

but (probably because `args.IsTerminating` is true) the application exit.
How can I handle the `SEHException` without exiting the application?

Comment: Are the exception actually thrown out to your WPF application or is simply caught by the debugger? If you native dll is handling the exception, the SEHException shouldn't reach your managed code.  Try telling you debugger not to break on SEHExceptions and you might find that it runs just fine. Either way, you shouldn't be throwing exceptions from native to ,managed code as you lose all the exception information when the exception is thrown as  SEHException.

Comment: The kind of "guard" exceptions are normally meant to tell you that you are doing it wrong.  Catching them doesn't solve anything, you'll have to change your code so the exception doesn't get thrown.  Enable unmanaged debugging so you can see what it actually complains about.  Or use a telephone.

Comment: I exactly know what the exceptions are because I am throwing it from my code. In C++ I use exceptions for defensive coding, with`REQUIRE, ENSURE, INVARIANT, CHECK` macros. These assertions throw exceptions that are defending the code; and in unmanaged C++ are properly catched and reported to help solving bugs, leaving the application in a safe state.